# How to decrease certain spacing intervals based on x-axis ticks

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, axis

I want to decrease the spacing intervals between certain ranges based on conditions on the X-Axis. In the picture I included, I want to condense the white regions between the grey blocks while increasing the grey blocks and moving them closer together. I am not sure if this is possible. This problem would be similar to having a timeline but taking out certain portions.The picture shows the white and grey regions I am referring to.

[image: The picture shows the white and grey regions I am referring to.]

I have tried adjusting the tics of the axis and changing the major locators.

```
ax.get_xaxis().set_major_locator(mdates.MonthLocator(interval=2))
ax.get_xaxis().set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter("%b %Y"))
plt.setp(ax.get_xticklabels(), rotation=30, ha="center")
```

Comment: Options would be (a) to plot against some index, instead of the actual dates, (b) use "broken axes", (c) create a custom nonlinear scale.